# Determining a greater than chance cutoff for an assessment's results

Tags: probability, likelihood

I recently collected a set of data, and before I completed an analysis of it, I wanted to remove any "bogus" entries from participants that didn't actually read the stories. The study I conducted had participants through the internet complete a comprehension assessment, that involved them reading six stories, and after each story, they answered 12 questions related to the details of that story. I only want to analyze data from participants that performed significantly greater than chance, because anyone who actually went through these stories should easily be able to surpass that mark I feel. However, i'm not sure how to determine what that mark should be. I'd like for someone to explain how to find a greater than chance cutoff (i.e with p < .05 or .01). I have SPSS, Python, and R at my disposal, if any of those tools would make it easier.

For some more reference, There are 72 questions in total, each question has 5 choices, and 223 participants completed the assessment. Each question is worth 1 point, so if someone is completely guessing, on average they would get a 14.4 / 72.

Comment: This question needs to be modified to disclose enough details of the assessment so that readers may give you qualified, objective advice about the role chance might play and how you can work with it quantitatively to obtain a good answer.

Comment: I just added more details to my question about the assessment, and some details about it. If this still seems too broad, let me know and i'll try to narrow it even further.